# c#: GUID Specified Value was out of range

Tags: c#, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using the heart Rate BLE windows 8.1 example

When I use the following two GUIDs everything works:

```
 <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <m2:DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.genericAttributeProfile">
      <m2:Device Id="any">
        <m2:Function Type="name:heartRate"/>
        <m2:Function Type="serviceId:b329392a-fbcd-49aa-a823-3e87680ac33b" />
      </m2:Device>
      <m2:Device Id="any">
        <m2:Function Type="name:genericAccess"/>
        <m2:Function Type="serviceId:ea2a0bd9-8296-4088-a995-3533b5b33941" />
      </m2:Device>
    </m2:DeviceCapability>
  </Capabilities>
```

But if I want to change the GUID using: [GUID Generator](https://www.guidgenerator.com/online-guid-generator.aspx)

```
     <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <m2:DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.genericAttributeProfile">
      <m2:Device Id="any">
        <m2:Function Type="name:heartRate"/>
        <m2:Function Type="serviceId:1a9d4963-e715-4f6e-9e07-4febf538f6a6" />
      </m2:Device>
      <m2:Device Id="any">
        <m2:Function Type="name:genericAccess"/>
        <m2:Function Type="serviceId:eef3f149-d420-4468-9def-1046fdcfe25e" />
      </m2:Device>
    </m2:DeviceCapability>
  </Capabilities>
```

the code throws an error:

```
Specified value is out of range
```

For this line of code:

```
characteristic.Add(device.Name, s.GetCharacteristics(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_R2)[CHARACTERISTIC_INDEX]);
```

Why does

```
eef3f149-d420-4468-9def-1046fdcfe25e
1a9d4963-e715-4f6e-9e07-4febf538f6a6
```

throw an error and the other two GUIDs do not?

```
b329392a-fbcd-49aa-a823-3e87680ac33b
ea2a0bd9-8296-4088-a995-3533b5b33941
```

When I debug with a working GUID:

```
Debug.WriteLine(s.GetCharacteristics(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_R2).Count);
```

It prints:

```
1
```

But with the new one **eef3f149-d420-4468-9def-1046fdcfe25e** or **1a9d4963-e715-4f6e-9e07-4febf538f6a6** it prints:

```
0
```

Answer:

Figured it out. I was confusing GUID with Characteristic UUID. For my device:

GUID: b329392a-fbcd-49aa-a823-3e87680ac33b
Characteristic UUDI: b329392b-fbcd-49aa-a823-3e87680ac33b

difference in **a** and **b**

Comment: If that XML shows Id 1 and 2, and you pass 3, what do you expect but an argument out of range? The accepted values are 1 and 2, don't try to pass 3 and expect it to work

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I edited the question to show how I changed the XML to include the new GUIDs. All I change is the GUID, and when I do it fails. The device can connect and I can print the device name, but the characteristic count is 0

Comment: Is this the entire XML?  Are there any DTD statements in the XML or references to an external namespace?

Comment: Please don't edit the question to include the answer, instead, post an actual answer and mark that as accepted

Answer (score 2):

if you are using c#, can get new Guid value like that

```
var guidValue = Guid.NewGuid();
```

updated:

Your GUID is valid, try this:

```
  var guidValue = Guid.Parse("b329392a-fbcd-49aa-a823-3e87680ac33b");
  Console.WriteLine(guidValue.ToString());
```

"eef3f149-d420-4468-9def-1046fdcfe25e" and "1a9d4963-e715-4f6e-9e07-4febf538f6a6" are valid too

[image]

Comment: I'll try this. SO you think my GUID is generated incorrectly?

Comment: Yes I have verified that b329392a-fbcd-49aa-a823-3e87680ac33b works fine but the other two do not:

Comment: "1a9d4963-e715-4f6e-9e07-4febf538f6a6" is valid too

Comment: The GUID is valid, you an see the picture, maybe if you are using a library for BLE, it has a issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The GUID was valid thus I was able to find that my characteristic value also had to change.